# Python PYQT QTreeWidgetItem selected cell

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem, treewidget

I have QTreeWidget like this

[image]

What should i do to get value from selected row and filename column ?

I have current selected item

```
 item = self.ui.files_treewidget.currentItem()
```

but how to access to specific cell?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `QTreeWidgetItem.text(column)`, where column is an integer.
In your example you would do:

```
item = self.ui.files_treewidget.currentItem()
filename = item.text(0)
size = item.text(1)
```